# What does [not(onchange)] mean in a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am upgrading an old version of jQuery (1.7.2) to a newer one and it blows up on a statement I don't understand:

```
$("select#searchtype[not(onchange)]", $criteria).change(function () {
   // do stuff
}
```

It blows up saying: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select#searchtype[not(onchange)]`.

I am assuming, the error refers to `[not(onchange)]`.  What does it mean? And more importantly, how do I upgrade it to the current version.

Comment: `[not(onchange)]` as far as I'm aware isn't a valid selector... thats why it says its unrecognised. Just delete the `[not(onchange)]` to make it work

Comment: @AshleyBrown This selector works fine in jQuery 1.7.2.  It must have been deprecated and removed between that and 1.12.x versions.  I just don't know what it does.

Comment: `:not([onchange])` *might* work - it refers to elements that do not have an inline `onchange` event attribute - however this doesn't exclude elements that have JS-bound event handlers.

Comment: @AngryHacker But does it work? Or does simply not error out?

Comment: @AngryHacker When you say it works, what works? Does it apply the event handler callback, and what to?

Comment: Kind of fascinating – `select#searchtype[not(onchange)]` doesn’t throw an error on 1.7.2 (and selects an element without any attributes other than `id`), but `#searchtype[not(onchange)]` *does* throw an error. Experimented a bit and `[not(onchange)]` didn’t seem to affect the result, though, so it does seem safe to remove.

Comment: @AshleyBrown Well, it doesn't error out.  I am not sure whether it works or not since I don't know how to trigger it.

Comment: @Ry- So you are saying just have it as `$("select#searchtype", $criteria).change(function () {` ?  And it would produce the same intent?

Comment: @AngryHacker: I’m saying it seems like that’s *functionally equivalent* (time to take a closer look at jQuery to make sure), but you should check whether it’s *correct*, because it certainly doesn’t seem like what was intended.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That does work and the method fires, but the current statement `select#searchtype[not(onchange)]` doesn't seem to fire in the older jQuery even though it doesn't blow up.  So perhaps it never worked at all.